# How to execute a closure on an optional type without unwrapping it?

Tags: swift, scala, option-type

I have a Swift optional type and I want to chain a transformation to it (`map`) and eventually pass it to a closure that prints it.

I want avoid unwrapping (using `!`) the optional type because I don't want to execute the closure unless we have something inside the optional.

In Scala we use `foreach` as a `map` that returns Unit.

```
val oi = Option(2)
oi.map(_+1).foreach(println)
```

In Swift I get only until the increment (and the conversion to string)

```
let oi:Int? = 1
let oiplus = oi.map({$0 + 1}).map({String($0)})
// now we have "2"
```

Now how do I give this to `print()` only in the case the optional is not nil?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would just map over it

```
let oi: Int? = 1
let oiplus = oi.map{ $0 + 1 }.map { String($0) }
oiplus.map { print($0) }
```

Arguably not nice to map for producing a side-effect, but there's no `foreach` for `Optional` in Swift.
This also produces an `unused result` warning in Swift 2.

If the semantic (and the warning) bug you, you can always define your own `foreach` for `Optional`. It's pretty straightforward:

```
extension Optional {
  func forEach(f: Wrapped -> Void) {
    switch self {
    case .None: ()
    case let .Some(w): f(w)
    }
  }
}
```

and then

```
let oi: Int? = 1
let oiplus = oi.map{ $0 + 1 }.map { String($0) }
oiplus.forEach { print($0) }
```

which resembles scala as much as possible.

Comment: Accepting this. Grazie Gabriele!

Answer (score 2):

While I usually do not recommend using `map` for side-effects, in this case I believe it's the cleanest Swift.

```
_ = oiplus.map{ print($0) }
```

There is now a `SequenceType.forEach` method that is explicitly for this problem, but `Optional` is not a `SequenceType`. You could of course extend `Optional` to add a `forEach`-like method (I'd probably call it `apply` in Swift).

It's worth noting that this just avoids the `if-lit`, which is barely any longer:

```
if let o = oiplus { print(o) }
```

But it admittedly doesn't chain as nicely as:

```
_ = oi
    .map { $0 + 1 }
    .map { print($0) }
```

See also http://www.openradar.me/23247992, which is basically Gabriele's answer.

Comment: Note very nice, but  `_ = oiplus.map{ print($0) }` avoids a "Result is unused" warning.